# Display non rectangular shaped TextBlock

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, wpf-controls, textblock

I want to display text in a triangular area. But I cannot figure out how to change the shape of the TextBlock so that text is displayed in triangular region instead of the regular rectangular region.

Here is the simplified code of my UserControl:

```
<Grid >
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" />   <!-- Some triangular image -->
    <TextBlock Height="100" Width="100" Text="This text should fill up the triangualr image area"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I got this problem in WPF but i guess it will be similar problem\solution in Silverlight. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: More often than many would normally realise solutions vary dramatically.  Always be very clear whether you need a solution for WPF, Silverlight or Both in your questions.

Comment: Ok. Sounds good. I thought this may of interest to both the forums since it is a common problem but if you think this is a concern then I would rather be careful next time. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is of interest to both and there is no harm in including both tags but it helps if the question is clear what actual platform the solution is needed for.

Comment: Should whole words be kept on the same line?  We will have a problem if the first word is "Antidisestablishmentarianism", right?

Answer (score 1):

Well kind of an overkill solution but the contents of the inner grid will be triangular in arrangement if something similar is followed:

```
 <Grid>
   <Image Height="200" Width="200" />
   <Grid Width="200">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition />
             <RowDefinition />
             <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="Line 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="This is Line 2." HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="This is Line 3. Wud be longest." HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

For your reference, The grid is constructed as follows :

[image: Refrence image]

Set the background triangular image & I suppose that suffices.

Comment: actually for simplicity I set the Text property explicitly in TextBlock in my Question. In actuality I am setting the Text through Binding. So breaking the text in 3 different parts as per text width will be complex.

Comment: @Souvik:  Whatever solution you end up using __will__ be complex.

Comment: @Anthony - using a template would probably be a cleaner solution (because you do not have to do arithmetic operations to find out text width). Even out of 2 complex solutions you can always have a lesser complex one and a more complex one. I am trying to find out the lesser complex and clean one.

Comment: @Souvik: You reckon you can do this without measuring text widths and doing arithmetic?  That would be great if you could but you should brace yourself for it because I don't think you are going to have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the TextBox's Template

I would recommend getting a copy of [Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx), extracting the TextBox's Template from there, and modifying it to suit your needs.

If you are unable to get Blend, I'd recommend [Show Me The Template](http://www.wpfpedia.com/item/details/105/showmethetemplate), which is a WPF tool that shows the default template for most WPF controls

Comment: I think you missed that OP wants to display text in a triangular region and not really in a triangular textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Rachel. I have Blend on my machine. But I am not sure how to set the Template to a triangular region so that the text displays there. Can you please give a sample xaml solution? I too will try to do it myself side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the template of the textbox, like this

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Textbox">
    <Path ... define your triangle here>               
</ControlTemplate>
```

and then set the enter property on the textbox to true. also align cont. hor. and vert. alg. that way it is centered in the middle of the triangle. make sure you make the textbox background transparent so it doesn't overwrite the triangle bounds.

also if you don't want to go outside the bounds, put the content presenter inside a viewbox.

you can also look into the clip property.